# isset() does not work correctly

Tags: php

Why `isset($_POST['string'])` works the same for php 5.3 and php 5.4?
After all, article http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php says that isset() will now work differently.

Comment: remove spaces between $_POST like `isset ($_POST ['string'])`

Comment: has nothing to do with `$_POST`. - *Non-numeric string offsets*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the description says:

> Non-numeric string offsets - e.g. $a['foo'] where $a is a string - now return false on isset() and true on empty(), and produce a E_WARNING if you try to use them.
>
> Offsets of types double, bool and null produce a E_NOTICE.
>
> Numeric strings (e.g. $a['2']) still work as before. Note that offsets like '12.3' and '5 foobar' are considered non-numeric and produce a E_WARNING, but are converted to 12 and 5 respectively, for backward compatibility reasons.

Note: Following code returns different result.

```
$str='abc';var_dump(isset($str['x'])); 
// false for PHP 5.4 or later, but true for 5.3 or less
```

---

It is only changed for strings treated as char arrays. For example:

```
$test = "str";
```

is equal to

```
$test = ['s','t','r'];
```

when being accessed with indexes.

Before PHP 5.4,

```
$test[2] will return 'r'
$test["2"] will also return 'r'
$test[2.3] will also return 'r'
$test["a"] will return false
isset($test["a"]) will return true
empty($test["a"]) will return false
```

After PHP 5.4

```
$test[2] will return 'r'
$test["2"] will also return 'r'
$test[2.3] will also return 'r', but with a warning
$test["a"] will return false and produce a warning
isset($test["a"]) will return false
empty($test["a"]) will return true
```

So,

`$_POST` is a real array, and `string` is a real key, it didn't change the way isset and empty acts on this.